# JavaFX Line Chart

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I am trying to create a line chart with some dummy data. The chart has been created using scene builder. Controller class and properties have been assigned.

My main application has method to open a new scene (popup window) for the line chart:

```
public void showStatistics() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Stats.fxml"));
    AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Statistics");
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(true);
    StatsController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.SetStatsData();
    stage.show();
}
```

My stats controller class with the dummy data:

```
public class StatsController {

@FXML final CategoryAxis catAxis = new CategoryAxis();
@FXML final NumberAxis numAxis = new NumberAxis();

@FXML final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(catAxis,numAxis);

@FXML
private void initialize() {     

    lineChart.setTitle("Overview");
    catAxis.setLabel("Date");
    numAxis.setLabel("Price");
}

public void setStatsData() {

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series = new Series<String, Number>();

    ArrayList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        data.add(i, new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("" + (i + 1), 0));
    }

    series.getData().addAll(data);
    lineChart.getData().add(series);
}   
}
```

When I run the method of my main class all I get is an empty chart. Can someone help?

Comment: In other words **don't** initialise @FXML variables

Comment: changing declarations from "final" to "private" resolved the issue